# How to make legend have no number overlap in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, legend

I'd like my legend to go from 0-25 to 26-50 to 51-75 rather than what it is in the screenshot included.

How should I go about doing that?

[image: legend]

```
  function getColor(d) {
    return d >= 75
      ? "#2c7bb6"
      : d >= 50
      ? "#abd9e9"
      : d >= 25
      ? "#fdae61"
      : d > 0
      ? "#d7191c"
      : "#d3d3d3";
  }

// 4. create the legend

  var legend = L.control({ position: "bottomright" });

  legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "legend"),
      grades = [0, 25, 50, 75],
      labels = [];

    div.innerHTML = '<i style="background:#d3d3d3"></i> No data<br>';

    // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval

    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
      div.innerHTML +=
        '<i style="background:' +
        getColor(grades[i] + 1) +
        '"></i> ' +
        grades[i] +
        (grades[i + 1] ? "&ndash;" + grades[i + 1] + "<br>" : "+");
    }

    return div;
  };

  legend.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a GIS question, but pure HTML/JS one, but anyway ...

To display the desired legend, you have first to change the `getColor()` function, so that it reflects your desired value ranges:

```
function getColor(d) {
  return d > 75
    ? "#2c7bb6"
    : d > 50
    ? "#abd9e9"
    : d > 25
    ? "#fdae61"
    : d >= 0
    ? "#d7191c"
    : "#d3d3d3";
}
```

Then you have to modify your legend generating part to reflect your desired ranges, adding `1` to lower bound if value if value is not `0`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
  var lowValue = (grades[i] > 0) ? (grades[i] + 1) : grades[i];
  var highValue = grades[i + 1];
  div.innerHTML +=
    '<i style="background:' +
    getColor(grades[i] + 1) +
    '"></i> ' +
    lowValue +
    (highValue ? "&ndash;" + highValue + "<br>" : "+");
}
```